# WCF - Returning A Custom List

Tags: wcf

I'm working with WCF and trying to return a list (or an array) of objects back to my client.
It seems to be working fine for standard types, and I can return custom objects, but not lists of custom objects (even if there is only one item in the list).

I've read a fair amount on the topic but can't seem to get anywhere with it.
It's compiling ok, but on the client side, when I get to my function, the client throws an exception

> "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details."

I've tried a few ideas, currently my object looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
    public class FilePacket : IDisposable
    {
        //[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        [DataMember]
        public string fileName;

        //[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        [DataMember]
        public long fileSize;

        //[MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        [DataMember]
        public System.IO.Stream fileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (fileByteStream != null)
            {
                fileByteStream.Close();
                fileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your operation contract look like?

Comment: I've tried [OperationContract] FilePacket syncStuff(); [OperationContract] FilePacket[] syncStuff();
[OperationContract] List<FilePacket> syncStuff();
etc

Comment: [OperationContract] FilePacket[] syncStuff();  seems to right and should work.

Comment: Can you just return a list of objects where the stream property is null for testing if its a problem with your custom object.

Comment: Rajesh, good suggestion! It does work if the stream is null. So what should I do now?

Comment: Adding [IgnoreDataMember] to fileByteStream also stops the issue (presumably as this is essentially the same as leaving it to be null)

Comment: @Chris "public System.IO.Stream fileByteStream;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now got this working (thanks for the help folks).
There seems to be a variety of things that can go wrong and cause problems.
Firstly, I changed from a Stream to a MemoryStream; and made sure it was being used as such throughout (I did notice while trying a few options that you can set the DataContract up to use a Stream, and actually be using a FileStream; this caused havoc, and took a few minutes to notice).

I changed from DataContract to MessageContract (ensuring to set the MemoryStream as [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]).

In the App Config, I set my transferMode to "Streamed" and ensured the  maxBufferSize was set to a huge value.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to do is check whether you are using `transferMode` as `Streamed` in binding.

```
<system.serviceModel>
     …
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     …
<system.serviceModel>
```

Second thing you should use `MessageContract`.

```
[MessageContract]
public class FilePacket
{
   [MessageHeader]
   public string fileName;

   [MessageBodyMember]
   public System.IO.Stream fileByteStream;

   ...
}
```

Other than the `fileByteStream` the remaining properties you should decorate with `MessageHeader` attribute.

The final thing is make sure you have set correct value for `maxReceivedMessageSize` property to overcome the size limitations.

See these references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the response.
I've given your suggestions a try, unfortunately, the behaviour is still the same. A null fileByteStream will pass through fine, but otherwise I get an exception.